# Unable to change GUI size in MATLAB's GUIDE interface

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

For some reason I am unable to resize the workspace size of a GUI figure using MATLAB's built in GUIDE editor. Every time I do so (by dragging the corner of the workspace), I get a warning in MATLAB's console stating:

```
Warning: Cannot set Position while WindowStyle is 'docked' 
> In guidefunc>resizeFigure at 2693
  In guidefunc at 116
```

I have tried setting the default window style to 'normal' (`set(0,'DefaultFigureWindowStyle','normal')`) to no avail.

I see no reports of this strange behaviour elsewhere online, and wonder if anyone else has experienced this?

Am using MATLAB R2012a. Any thoughts appreciated(!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default-Window-Style and Window-Style are two different things. If you want to change the WindowStyle, you should use that property.
In addition take care for the handle of the figure!

```
%get handle:
myFigure= findobj('Tag','SomeUniqueTagHere') %make sure to get the right one
set(myFigure,'WindowStyle','normal')
```

I guess (but I'm not absolutely sure) default-properties will just be used during creation.

Answer (score 1):

Improving upon [Lucius'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2572698/lucius-ii) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19629108/6997665), I was able to resize the figure after using the following command on the workspace window.

```
set(gcf,'WindowStyle','normal')
```

This command helps sets the window style to normal and hence is resize-able.

I am using Matlab R2020b and the figure under question was selected (highlighted) before I ran this command.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the workspace in GUI and therefore avoid the error message

> Warning: Cannot set Position while WindowStyle is 'docked'

by changing the setting `WindowStyle` in the GUI. To the end you should:

1. Go to the GUI
2. Double click on the background, which makes appear the inspector panel.
3. Go to the property `WindowStyle` and change it from `docked` to `normal`.

After that you can resize your workspace normally.